# Only activate actionButton when Shiny app is not busy

Tags: r, button, shiny, shinyjs

I have an `actionButton()` in my webpage that makes some computation, and it finishes 20 or 30 seconds later.

Is there any way to disable the button while the app is running? Or any other approach could be interesting too. I am asking this because some users of my app double-clicks the `actionButton` and I can see in the server that the calculations are run twice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable button after it is clicked and enable it again on exit. It can be done manually but `shinyjs` already provides required helpers.

If function called on click may fail you can use `tryCatch` with `finally` to make sure that your app won't stay in the disabled state:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

foo <- function() {
    Sys.sleep(4)
    x <- runif(1)
    if(x < 0.5) stop("Fatal error")
    print(x)
}

shinyApp(
    ui=shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
        useShinyjs(),
        actionButton("go", "GO")
    )),
    server=shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
        observe({
            if(input$go == 0) return()
            shinyjs::disable("go")

            tryCatch(
                foo(),          
                error = function(e) return(),
                finally = shinyjs::enable("go")
            )
        })
    })
)
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use the disable functionality on pretty much all the inputs with functionality from `shinyjs` package. Below I created somewhat intensive operation and the button will deactivate while the table is generated so the users cannot press it multiple times unless the output is generated first.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

ui =fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("numbers", "Number of records", 1000000, 5000000, 1000000, sep = ""),
    actionButton("goButton","GO")
  ),
  mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput('table'))
)

server = function(input, output, session){

  My_Data<-reactive({
    if (is.null(input$goButton) || input$goButton == 0){return()}
    isolate({
      input$goButton
      # Disable a button
      disable("goButton")
      # below is your intensive operation
      a <- round(rnorm(input$numbers),2)
      b <- round(rnorm(input$numbers),2) 
      # Enable a button again
      enable("goButton")
      data.frame("a" = a, "b" = b)
    })
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(withProgress(datatable(My_Data(),options = list(searching = FALSE,pageLength = 10,lengthMenu = c(5,10, 50))),message = "Generating Data"))
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```